# How to keep value in variable after refresh page in PHP?

Tags: php

I writing simple game.  I randomizes two numbers and then user put your sum value number to  input form whose I sent on the same site. Now  if  user guess sum numbers it he get 10 points, but if he will miss, lost  one chance.

I have problem, because if i Refresh site i  overiate   he points and chance. Any solution?

```php
     $_SESSION['points'];
    //$_SESSION['chance'];
     $X = rand(1, 10);
    $Y = rand(1, 10);
     echo $X . " " . $Y;
     ?>

      <form name="MyForm" action="" method="POST">

    <input type="text" name="value">
    <input type="hidden" value="<?= $X ?>" name="number">
    <input type="hidden" value="<?= $Y ?>" name="number2">
    <input type="submit" value="Generuj" name="Wynik?"/>

    </form>
    <?php
     if (!empty($_POST) && isset($_POST)) {
       $user = $_POST['value'];


        
     if ($_POST['number'] * $_POST['number2'] == $user) {
       
      echo ' ok !';
     echo $_SESSION['points'] += 10;

          } else {
        echo 'error';
        // echo 'You lost one chance' . $_SESSION['chance']--;

    }

    }
```

Comment: Do you have `session_start()` in your script?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use a PHP session OR a PHP Cookie.

Using [cookies](http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php) (if information is not sensible)

```
   <?php 
        $value = 'something from somewhere';
        setcookie("TestCookie", $value);
        setcookie("TestCookie", $value, time()+3600);  /* expire in 1 hour */ 
   ?>
```

Then you can echo your cookie like this

```
  <?php 
     echo $_COOKIE['TestCookie'];
  ?>
```

If you're using [Sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php)

```
<?php 
   session_start();
   $_SESSION['myVar'] = $myValue;
?>
```

Then you can echo it that way

```
<?php 
   echo $_SESSION['myVar'];
?>
```

NOTE that with the session, you always have to start your session at the beginning of your PHP file.

Comment: It's probably not a good idea to put random numbers in a cookie. OP seems have some kind of lottery mechanic.

Comment: It depends of the nature of the game I'd say, that's why I wrote both way with PHP to keep session if you restart, idk why you guys are down-voting...

Comment: Can you explain under what circumstance a 100% cheatable mechanic would be acceptable?

Comment: If it's a small game where it doesn't matter (since there is no price whatsoever) or leaderboard, you could save it in a cookie. But I agree with you that it,s most likely that he should use session