# Saving the login after refreshing the page

Tags: php

I have created a unique username generator. The problem is that it doesn't get saved in the form after refreshing the page.

Is there a way to stop this?

HERE IS THE LOGIN GENERATION CODE:

```
<div>
     <label for="username">Ваш логін</label>
     <input type="text" name="username" value="' .
         (strval(bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(1)))) . date("Y") . 
         (strval(bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(1)))) . date("d") . 
         (strval(bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(1)))) . date("m") . 
         (strval(bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(1)))) . '" 
         readonly="readonly">  
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [php keep value in variable after refresh site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33767794/php-keep-value-in-variable-after-refresh-site)

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't get saved in form"? As in, the input is empty when you refresh the page?

Comment: Have you tried `echo`-ing 
         (strval(bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(1)))) . date("Y") . 
         (strval(bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(1)))) . date("d") . 
         (strval(bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(1)))) . date("m") . 
         (strval(bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(1))))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are generating a username in the page but not storing it.

This is an example where I send the generated username via POST with a submit button and then use the php session to store the username for this user:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(isset($_POST['username'])) {
        $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
    }

    if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
        $value = $_SESSION['username'];
    } else {
        $value = (strval(bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(1)))) . date("Y") .
        (strval(bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(1)))) . date("d") .
        (strval(bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(1)))) . date("m") .
        (strval(bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(1))));
    }
?>

<form action="" method="post">
    <label for="username">Ваш логін</label>
    <input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo $value; ?>"
    readonly="readonly">
    <input type="submit" value="Save username">
</form>
```

After storing the username I make a simple if statement, if there is a username stored use that one, else generate a new one.